# normal projection

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a complex inner product space X.
A linear operator A : X $\rightarrow$ X satisfies A$^2$ = A and A$^{*}$A = AA$^{*}$. Because X = R$_A$ $\oplus$ R$_A$$^{\perp}$ ,
 then pick x = m$+$n, in which m $\in$ R$_A$ , n $\in$ R$_A$$^{\perp}$, x $\in$ X.
I need to show Ax = m. I can show it until $\langle$ Ax, Ay $\rangle$ =  $\langle$ m, A$^*$Ay $\rangle$.  But feel difficult to show
Ay = A$^{*}$Ay. Is there any other wise way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first observe that $\|Au\|^{2}=\|A^{*}u\|^{2}$. $\,\,$ (1) LHS is $ \langle Au, Au \rangle = \langle A^{*}Au, u \rangle =\langle AA^{*}u, u \rangle =\langle A^{*}u, A^{*}u \rangle $ which is RHS. This proves (1). Now let $u \in R_A^{\perp}$. Then $\langle u, Av \rangle =0$ for all $v$ which implies  $\langle A^{*}u, v \rangle =0$ for all $v$. Thus $A^{*}u=0$. From (1) we can now conclude that $Au=0$. Now $Ax=A(m+n)=Am+An=Am$. It remains to show that $Am=m$. But $m=Az$ for some $z$ so $Am=A^{2}z=Az=m$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\ m\in \mathrm{R}_A\ $, then $\ m=Az\ $ for some $\ z\in X\ $, so $ Am=A^2 z = Az=m\ $, because $\ A^2=A\ $. Also, $\ \langle An, An\rangle\ = \langle A^*An,n\rangle= \langle AA^*,n\rangle\ = 0\ $, because $\ n\in \mathrm{R}_A\,^\perp\ $, so $\ An=0\ $.  Thus, $\ Ax= Am+An = m+0=m\ $.